# Can I have non html-based View in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does asp.net mvc support other views rather than html? Can I have Xml view? Or text view? In .csxml, cstxt, etc files? Then populate them with the Razor engine / syntax and model data same way I would use .cshtml and return with a proper mime type?

Update: my question is not about how to return text or xml from asp.net mvc. I want to use view engine to populate them.

Update2: Specifically, I want to know if I can have 2 different views taking the same model:

1st one is html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>First Name: @Model.FirstName, Last Name: @Model.LastName</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd xml view view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<FirstName>@Model.FirstName</FirstName>
<LastName>@Model.LastName</LastName>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return json using the [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), return a file (from the drive or from a byte array) using the [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), or return your own result ([like xml](http://blog.kurtschindler.net/creating-an-actionresult-that-returns-xml-with-asp-net-mvc/)) deriving from ActionResult.  Since you aren't clear on what you ACTUALLY want, this is probably the best I can do.

Comment: I know what I want - Xml output with some values populated by razor view engine from my model, same way I am getting html.

Comment: You want to put HTML in XML?  Again you aren't doing well describing what you actually want.

Comment: I don't want any html. I want to have xml (or text) view / template and razor fill it in and asp.net returning it with appropriate mime type.

Comment: Razor isn't a *return anything* type of templating engine, it's an html template engine. Writing your own templating engine for xml sounds like a terrible idea.  Since XML does not contain external content (images, css, javscript, etc), you're much MUCH better off transforming your data, serializing it to XML, and returning it.

Comment: So your answer is no - I can't use any other view types than html?

Comment: Anyway, I know for a fact that razor can be used outside of asp.net mvc for any type of views, not just html. Now i want to use it inside of asp.net mvc for the broader purpose.